# awscli not in the path on macOS

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, pip, homebrew, aws-cli

I have so far tried installed `awscli` via the commandline and via the interactive installer , using `brew` and `pip` however I cannot use the aws command due to path configuration

```
which aws

/usr/local/bin
```

But when I try

`aws --version` I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws: No such file or directory
```

How can I have aws command run from the correct location?
I also tried running `aws` command from `/usr/local/bin` but have the same error

I have tried this in a new shell  and this is aws cli v2
also tried this

```
type aws
aws is hashed (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws)
```

Comment: Did you start a new shell before testing this? And did you install awscli v1 or v2?

Comment: That does not look like awscli installed via brew because it's using python 2 instead of python 3.

Comment: Try instead `type aws`

Comment: Or be specific `/usr/local/bin/aws --version`

Comment: @MarkSetchell updated question

Comment: using /usr/local/bin/aws --version gives the same error

Comment: What's the output from `ls -l /usr/local/bin/aws` please?

Comment: Can you run `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws --version` ?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/aws --version

aws-cli/2.0.23 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.4.0 botocore/2.0.0dev27
```

Solution:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 0):

If having issues updating/upgrading the awscliv1 to v2.
Take the following step:

1. rm -rf /bin/aws
2. curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-aarch64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
3. unzip awscliv2.zip
4. ./aws/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /bin
   export the PATH to the bin/aws previously remove
5. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/aws